# RAID 5 controller port multiplier

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, hardware-failure, hardware-raid

I have 6x320GB HDD and I was considering to create a RAID 5 system (it's for storage only).

I use ubuntu 14.04 and I want to ask what RAID controller card allows for 4 (or more) ports without requiring too much configuration under Linux-Ubuntu.

As said, the goal would be to be able to use all 6 drives in a RAID 5 system.

Comment: Hardware purchase recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser.  Just use your favorite source for computer parts, and locate a RAID controller, that fulfills your requirements.

Comment: i'll move it to a different forum, but thanks for helping out.

Comment: We are not a forum.  Consider reading the guidelines on what makes a good question, at hardware recommendation SE, before you ask this question there though.